# Static variable to change in a child class from a parent

Tags: c#, static

I want to create a child class of Dog, Cat, Lion, etc. I want each animal to create an object of itself. When it creates on object of itself I want it to keep track of how many total types of animals there are. So for example if there are 3 dogs then the dog class knows it has 4 dogs. The same for all the others.

Example code for Dog:

```
class Dog {
    static int numberOfDogs = 0;

    public Dog() {
    }

    public void AddDog() {
        numberOfDogs++;
    }

    public void MinusDog() {
        numberOfDogs--;
    }
}
```

Now if I want to do the same thing for a cat I would need to rewrite all that code and replace `dog` with `cat` and so on.

What I want to do is create a parent class that has all that repeated code in one spot but as I create a Dog it will add to the dog variable and the same with the cat and so on. My idea of the parent class:

```
class Animal {
    public static int NumberOfAnimals;

    public void AddAnimal() {
        NumberOfAnimals++;
    }

    public void MinusAnimal() {
        NumberOfAnimals--;
    }
}
```

If I derive `Dog` from `Animal` and call `dog.AddAnimal()` it will add to all the `Animal`'s static variable. How can I make to so that I have a static variable in `Dog` that can be changed using the parent class `Animal`?

Or if I'm asking the wrong question, how can I get the desired result of having many animals with many static variables?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced the class itself is the right place to count how many you have. But there's not enough information in your question to make a good assessment of the broader goal.

As far as what you're asking goes, you have lots of options. Here are a couple…

One simple approach would be for the base class to have a dictionary:

```
class Animal
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, int> _counts =
        new Dictionary<Type, int>();

    protected Animal()
    {
        int count;

        _counts.TryGetValue(this.GetType(), out count);
        _counts[this.GetType()] = count + 1;
    }
}

class Dog : Animal { ... }
```

Another option would be to let the runtime handle the type-specific counts:

```
class Animal<T>
{
    private static int _count;

    protected Animal()
    {
        _count++;
    }
}

class Dog : Animal<Dog> { ... }
```

To elaborate on this second option, since it may be a bit confusing to someone new to C#. Starting with your comment…

> What is the <T> that you have there?

That's part of the declaration of the `Animal<T>` class, which makes it a *generic* class. That is, the class, when used, must be provided a type parameter (i.e. the name of some *other* type), where that type parameter specializes the generic type in a useful way (where "useful" depends on exactly how you're using it). In this particular case, my example makes the base class generic, to take advantage of the fact that static fields of a generic type are unique *for each different type parameter that is used*.

That is, for the declared class `class Dog : Animal<Dog> { ... }`, the field `_count` in the base class is actually a *different* variable than for some other declared class, e.g. `class Cat : Animal<Cat> { ... }`. In that way, each subclass such as `Dog`, `Cat`, etc. gets their own value for that field.

In either case, you still need to work out how you'd like to actually be able to *get* the counts and use them. It's not clear from your question how that fits in.

Note also that none of the above is thread-safe, while static members typically are expected to be. I've omitted that part, but you'll want to add synchronization to ensure thread-safety, so there are no surprises.

All of that said, if this is in fact over your head, and you are in fact just starting to learn about OOP, inheritance, and C#, I would go back to my original statement, that I'm not convinced implementing this in the class itself is actually the right place.

A better approach would be to have some other class that knows about the different `Animal` objects you are creating, and which keeps track of them in some way. For example, it could have a `Dictionary<Type, List<Animal>>`, where the key `Type` can be e.g. `typeof(Dog)`, `typeof(Cat)`, etc. and the value `List<Animal>` can just be a list of the particular type of `Animal` object. Then not only do you have immediate access to the count (since the `List<T>` class has a `Count` property), you can also immediately retrieve all of the objects you created.

I can't be more specific than that because, again, your question is fairly vague about what you are actually going to do with these objects. If all you're trying to do is to learn about OOP and how inheritance works, maybe it's better to just not worry about the *count* of objects you create for now. There's still plenty of other stuff you could focus on which will still give you substance to think about. :)

Comment: Almost all of this has gone way over me head. This is just a problem I've created myself to learn about class inheritance and it looks like I have overstepped my bounds. What is the <T> that you have there? I have seen it so many times but haven't had the time to dive into it.

Comment: The Best Solution :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good design but I preferred to stick to your main idea.
Please notice that a generic class would be a perfect solution for you.

Take a look at this :

Abstract animal class

```
public abstract class Animal
    {
        public static List<Type> AnimalList=new List<Type>();

        protected Animal(Type animalType)
        {

            AnimalList.Add(animalType);
        }   
    }
```

Dog as a child class

```
 public class Dog : Animal
  {
    public Dog(Type animalType) : base(animalType)
    {

    }
    public static int CountDogs
    {
        get { return AnimalList.Count(x => x == typeof (Dog)); }
    }
  }
```

Main Method :

```
Animal a =new Dog(typeof(Dog));
Animal a1=new Dog(typeof(Dog));
var c = Dog.CountDogs;
```

Comment: Note that this proposal has some deficiencies. First, it still requires a separate method in each subclass to retrieve the count. Second, retrieving the count is an O(n) operation, which is bad enough, but on top of that `n` is _all_ of the `Animal` objects, not just the particular type in question. Third, if one must implement it this way, it would make lots more sense to write `AnimalList.OfType<Dog>().Count()`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want Class Dog to be derived class of Animal so that you can access Class Animal from  Class dog you have to do ->

`class Animal{

public void AddAnimal(int &NumberOfAnimals;)
 { NumberOfAnimals++; }

public void MinusAnimal(int &NumberOfAnimals)
 { NumberOfAnimals--; }
 }

class Dog: public Animal {

int numberOfDogs = 0;

Animal obj;

public void AddDog()
 { obj. AddAnimal(numberOfDogs); }

public void MinusDog() { obj.MinusAnimal(numberOfDogs); } }'

If you want to make numberOfDogs static you won't be able to increase or decrease it's value when you add or minus